# how to fix wrong utf character in string assignement?

Tags: python, python-3.x, utf

I have a python3.6 loop doing the following:

```
childrenList = []

output["text"] = path

for item in sorted(os.listdir(path)):
    contentFullPath = os.path.join(path, item)
    children = {}

    if os.path.isfile(contentFullPath):
        print("item = "+str(item))
        children["text"] = item
        print("children = "+str(children))
        children["id"] = contentFullPath
        childrenList.append(children)
```

I'm getting the following output:

```
web_1     | item = Obamaééé.mp4
web_1     | children = {'icon': 'jstree-file', 'text': 
            'Obamae\udccc\udc81e\udccc\udc81e\udccc\udc81.mp4'}
```

Why is the text from the variable named children not correctly displayed ?

Comment: The `str()` of a container object, such as your dictionary in this case, is built from the `repr()` of its contained elements, rather than their `str()`.  Both displays are correct, they're just in different formats.

Comment: but then why do I get the following error ?

     children["text"] = item.encode().decode()
     $UnicodeEncodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't encode character '\udccc' in position 8: surrogates not allowed

Answer (score -1):

```
import unidecode

text = 'Obamaééé.mp4'
strip_text = unidecode.unidecode(text.decode('utf-8'))
print(strip_text)

[output] : Obamaeee.mp4
```

Hopefully this helps you.

Comment: children["text"] = unidecode(item.decode('utf-8'))
    AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'

Comment: I assume they meant to use `encode`, but either way, this isn't a real answer; it's stripping diacritics (changing the string), which is only a "fix" in the same sense that burning your house down fixes bad wallpaper.